# jquery dd-mm-yyyy format and disabling future dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, maxdate

I want the dates to be in `dd-mm-yyyy` format and have to block future dates from selection.

I am using the following code:

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({maxDate: "+0D" });
        } );
</script>
```

But only the first line in the function works; i.e. date is in `dd-mm-yyyy` but the disabling of future dates is not achieved.

Comment: Is it jQuery UI datepicker ?

Comment: which datepicker?

Comment: Yeah. jQuery datepicker

Comment: Now I have another field in the same webpage where datepicker has to be in MM-YYYY format. The system should not allow future month-year combinations. Any suggestions and code snippets will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", maxDate: 0});
```

Comment: Thank you Alex.
Now I have another field in the same webpage where datepicker has to be in MM-YYYY format. The system should not allow future month-year combinations. Any suggestions and code snippets will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for future date disabling.

```
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({  
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
maxDate: new Date() });});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using below codes,

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  maxDate: '0'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text">
```